# Perl method fails when I use a variable as opposed to a string literal

Tags: perl

Getting some odd behaviour in a Perl script that I don't quite understand. I'm trying to make some of my magic string literals into variables that can be modified more easily.

I have an argument in my subprocedure called `$in_feature`.  Right now it's value is simply `"in_feature"`. I can print it out and it looks fine. So far so good...

This code fails, though:

```
if ($in_feature != "" && !$blockModel->is_field($in_feature))
{
    print "ERROR: was expecting to find a variable in the block model called $in_feature.\n";
        return;
}
```

If I remove the string comparison and change the method call back to the string literal it works as expected.

```
if (!$blockModel->is_field("in_feature"))
{
    print "ERROR: was expecting to find a variable in the block model called $in_feature.\n";
        return;
}
```

So the variable is somehow a string, that is equal to empty string, and can't be used in place of a string?!? Why's this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String comparison in perl uses ne and eq instead of != and ==

Replace `$in_feature != ""` with `$in_feature ne ""` and it might fix your issues.

Comment: @Coxy, It's spelled "Perl", and it loudly warns about this if you use `use warnings;` as you should.